# MariaDB can't be installed

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, mariadb

I got a problem with installing mariaDB on my linux/ubuntu server.
I try to install it but ist got an error(you can see the complete console log under) and I have no idea how to fix it and I don#t found any solution for this problem online.

```
root@vmd92300:~# pip3 install mariadb==1.1.6
Collecting mariadb==1.1.6
  Using cached mariadb-1.1.6.tar.gz (83 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting packaging (from mariadb==1.1.6)
  Using cached packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mariadb
  Building wheel for mariadb (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for mariadb (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [36 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb
      copying mariadb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb
      copying mariadb/connectionpool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb
      copying mariadb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/CAPABILITY.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/CURSOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/ERR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/FIELD_FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/INDICATOR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/INFO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/STATUS.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/constants/TPC_STATE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/constants
      copying mariadb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb
      copying mariadb/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb
      copying mariadb/field.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb
      copying mariadb/release_info.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb
      running build_ext
      building 'mariadb._mariadb' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -DPY_MARIADB_MAJOR_VERSION=1 -DPY_MARIADB_MINOR_VERSION=1 -DPY_MARIADB_PATCH_VERSION=6 -DPY_MARIADB_PRE_RELEASE_SEGMENT=\"None\" -DPY_MARIADB_PRE_RELEASE_NR=\"0\" -DPY_MARIADB_POST_RELEASE_SEGMENT=\"None\" -DPY_MARIADB_POST_RELEASE_NR=\"0\" -I/usr/include/mariadb -I/usr/include/mariadb/mysql -I./include -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c mariadb/mariadb.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/mariadb/mariadb.o -DDEFAULT_PLUGINS_SUBDIR=\"/usr/lib/mariadb/plugin\"
      In file included from mariadb/mariadb.c:21:
      ./include/mariadb_python.h:21:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
         21 | #include "Python.h"
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mariadb
Failed to build mariadb
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mariadb, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is:

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

In order to build the `mariadb` module you need the Python development libraries and header files. These need to be installed using your system package manager (unless you've built Python from source). On Redhat/Fedora/Centos/etc, that will be:

```
yum install python3-devel
```

On Debian/Ubuntu/etc, that will be:

```
apt install python3-dev
```

And on anything else, the general idea is the same but the specific commands may be different.

---

On a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 system, I only had to:

1. Install python3 and pip:

   ```
   apt install python3 python3-pip
   ```
2. Install the mariadb development libraries:

   ```
   apt install libmariadb-dev
   ```

After that I was able to successfully install the `mariadb` module:

```
root@af604c437a1e:/# pip3 install mariadb
Collecting mariadb
  Downloading mariadb-1.1.6.tar.gz (83 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 83.7/83.7 KB 3.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting packaging
  Using cached packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mariadb
  Building wheel for mariadb (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for mariadb: filename=mariadb-1.1.6-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl size=181894 sha256=269b7cb4d3fea8a4ed665d5fb924df881037107836437da7ab5ca734d82d2ccb
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8d/5c/30/26dc67e1971de894e0c55046043b0e20643ba15a662e575b6f
Successfully built mariadb
Installing collected packages: packaging, mariadb
Successfully installed mariadb-1.1.6 packaging-23.1
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
root@af604c437a1e:/# python3
Python 3.10.6 (main, Mar 10 2023, 10:55:28) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mariadb
>>>
```

Comment: it don't fixed the problem ist says the same like before

edit: i fixed the problem with "sudo apt-get install python3.x-dev"